# RaspberryPi: TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

Using DHT11 sensor and raspberrypi to collect temperature and humidity value.Please help me out with this error.Thanks in advance

```
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import time

while True:

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)

    print( 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity))
   # print()
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What results do you get by when you do print(humidity) and print(temperature)?

Comment: @Sojimanatsu  None None

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong with your read_retry method. Check it out what is the output of this read_retry(11,4) make sure that it does not refer to None object inside. You can see this by ctrl + clicking the read_retry method and see the return value.

Comment: @Sojimanatsu   could you please say in detail what is to be done

Comment: if it returns none does that mean there is problem with the hardware?

Comment: No, It does not mean that, I cant reproduce the error as I don't have the data. If you could share a part of your data, we can analyze it better. 
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/examples/AdafruitDHT.py
I found this example online, and check out, how do you get your entries to read. It seems wrong compare to this example. Try to change 11,4 to readable objects. So they don't return None.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help, after humidity,temeperature = Adafruit bla...bla...add line after that

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)

if humidity and temperature is not None:

```
print( 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity))
```

## print()

time.sleep(1)